# Polynomial Approximation of Holomorphic Functions

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, approximation, approximation-theory

Consider $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be open. Let $f:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic on $\Omega$. For any closed ball $B[a;r]$ in $\Omega$ does there exist a sequence of polynomials $(p_n(z))_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $p_n(z) \rightarrow f(z)$ uniformly on $B[a;r]$?

Comment: Yes - the partial sums of the Taylor series centered at $a$.